# Creating group based on time interval with stochastic base time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as:

| index | time |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-11 08:38:27 |
| 1 | 2021-01-11 08:40:32 |
| 2 | 2021-01-11 09:13:37 |
| 3 | 2021-01-11 11:26:52 |
| 4 | 2021-01-11 12:57:26 |
| 5 | 2021-01-11 13:19:33 |
| 6 | 2021-01-11 15:19:33 |
| 7 | 2021-01-12 10:25:33 |
| 8 | 2021-01-12 10:27:21 |
| 9 | 2021-01-12 11:02:13 |

I want to create another column based on one hour time difference from a stochastic base time. For example, when time at index 0 is the base time and I take one hour interval then index 0,1 and 2 is in the same group, say group_1. Next we can see that index 3 does not fall on group_1 since 08:38:27 + 1 hr = 09:38:27. So the next base time is at index 3 which is 2021-01-11 11:26:52. And this is group_2 and no other index fall on this group since the next index is more than one hour from this new base time. Then index 4 is the new base time and index 4 and 5 fall on the same group (group_3). And this process goes on upto the last row. The output should look like

| index | time | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-11 08:38:27 | group_1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-11 08:40:32 | group_1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-11 09:13:37 | group_1 |
| 3 | 2021-01-11 11:26:52 | group_2 |
| 4 | 2021-01-11 12:57:26 | group_3 |
| 5 | 2021-01-11 13:19:33 | group_3 |
| 6 | 2021-01-11 15:25:33 | group_4 |
| 7 | 2021-01-12 10:25:33 | group_5 |
| 8 | 2021-01-12 10:27:21 | group_5 |
| 9 | 2021-01-12 11:02:13 | group_5 |

Would really appreciate your time and answers. TIA.

Comment: If you need to count the 1 hour interval based on all entries in the time series rather than 1 hour difference from the previous entry in the series, please take a look at my analysis below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` on the negate condition to identify the block:

```
df['group'] = 'group_' + df['time'].diff().gt('1H').cumsum().add(1).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
                      time    group
index                              
0      2021-01-11 08:38:27  group_1
1      2021-01-11 08:40:32  group_1
2      2021-01-11 09:13:37  group_1
3      2021-01-11 11:26:52  group_2
4      2021-01-11 12:57:26  group_3
5      2021-01-11 13:19:33  group_3
6      2021-01-11 15:19:33  group_4
7      2021-01-12 10:25:33  group_5
8      2021-01-12 10:27:21  group_5
9      2021-01-12 11:02:13  group_5
```

Comment: There is one case not in sample data that this logics may fail.  E.g. index 3 has time `'2021-01-11 09:40:52',`  it should be in group_2 as it is more than one hour from the time of index 0, but it is still less than one hour difference from the time of index 2.

Comment: I have come up with revised codes to cater for the case I commented.  Please take a look and feel free to fine-tune it further.  Just friendly discussion of solution  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this question needs further analysis and requires another solution so hereby would like to review it.

According to the question, any 2 entries with time difference more than 1 hour should be classified in different groups.  So let's say we have the following 2 entries of `time`:

```
2021-01-11 08:38:27
2021-01-11 09:40:52
```

They differs by more than 1 hours and should be grouped under different group, right ?  Obvious, isn't it ?

Ok, let's add 2 more entries with time between them, like below:

```
2021-01-11 08:38:27      <=== original entry #1   
2021-01-11 08:40:32           <=== new entry #1    diff less than 1 hour from previous entry
2021-01-11 09:13:37           <=== new entry #2    diff less than 1 hour from previous entry
2021-01-11 09:40:52      <=== original entry #2    diff less than 1 hour from previous entry
```

Now, if we run code based on difference between 2 consecutive entries being less than 1 hour, let's see what we get:

```
df['group'] = 'group_' + df['time'].diff().gt('1H').cumsum().add(1).astype(str)


print(df)

                  time    group
0  2021-01-11 08:38:27  group_1
1  2021-01-11 08:40:32  group_1
2  2021-01-11 09:13:37  group_1
3  2021-01-11 09:40:52  group_1
```

Oh, **how come the last entry is `group_1` rather than `group_2` ?**

This is because **the 2 new entries added between the first and last entries somewhat 'bridge up' the first and last entry and make every 2 consecutive entries with difference less than 1 hour.**  Hence, the result.

So, what should we do ?   I think we should ***group the entries base on an absolute base reference point, which is not the previous entry, but an entry that stays constant as long as we are processing entry within one hour from that base reference point.***

I have come up with codes below:

```
base = df['time'].loc[0]
gc_list = []

for _, time in df['time'].items():
    if time - base > pd.Timedelta('1h'):
        base = time
    gc_list.append(time - base)

df['group_cumsum'] = pd.Series(gc_list)

df['group'] = 'group_' + df['group_cumsum'].eq('0h').cumsum().astype(str) 

print(df)

                  time    group_cumsum    group
0  2021-01-11 08:38:27 0 days 00:00:00  group_1
1  2021-01-11 08:40:32 0 days 00:02:05  group_1
2  2021-01-11 09:13:37 0 days 00:35:10  group_1
3  2021-01-11 09:40:52 0 days 00:00:00  group_2
```

Now, you can see that the last entry is correctly grouped under a separate group now.

Here, I adapted @Quang Hoang's code (which is excellent and elegant) and fine-tuned to use the new mechanism of classifying groups.  I had been trying to code in a more idiomatic way without using loop. However, as the logics has to rely on a local variable `base`, I can't find a better way to do it.  Feel free to suggest if there is any better way.

I enclosed complete codes (with additional test cases) below in case anyone is interested:

### Complete Codes

```
data = {'time': [
'2021-01-11 08:38:27',
'2021-01-11 08:40:32',
'2021-01-11 09:13:37',
'2021-01-11 09:40:52',
'2021-01-11 12:57:26',
'2021-01-11 13:19:33',
'2021-01-11 15:19:33',
'2021-01-12 10:25:33',
'2021-01-12 10:27:21',
'2021-01-12 11:02:13',
'2021-01-12 11:30:00'
]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

base = df['time'].loc[0]
gc_list = []

for _, time in df['time'].items():
    if time - base > pd.Timedelta('1h'):
        base = time
    gc_list.append(time - base)

df['group_cumsum'] = pd.Series(gc_list)

df['group'] = 'group_' + df['group_cumsum'].eq('0h').cumsum().astype(str)

print(df)

                  time    group_cumsum    group
0  2021-01-11 08:38:27 0 days 00:00:00  group_1
1  2021-01-11 08:40:32 0 days 00:02:05  group_1
2  2021-01-11 09:13:37 0 days 00:35:10  group_1
3  2021-01-11 09:40:52 0 days 00:00:00  group_2
4  2021-01-11 12:57:26 0 days 00:00:00  group_3
5  2021-01-11 13:19:33 0 days 00:22:07  group_3
6  2021-01-11 15:19:33 0 days 00:00:00  group_4
7  2021-01-12 10:25:33 0 days 00:00:00  group_5
8  2021-01-12 10:27:21 0 days 00:01:48  group_5
9  2021-01-12 11:02:13 0 days 00:36:40  group_5
10 2021-01-12 11:30:00 0 days 00:00:00  group_6
```